# Is there a way to hook into the checkout event in Magento?

Tags: api, magento

I'm creating a custom module that needs to hook in to the checkout success event in Magento.

What I need to do is this:

1). Once a custom has successfully checked out I need to present a special offer on the success page with a yes/no radio button and submit form. If they select yes I need to add their details to a custom grid in Magento backend that I have already created.

2). I then need to make an API call to a third party CRM using the POST method to authenticate and add the customers details to their billing system.

3). Upon completion there needs to be a way to update the Grid in Magento to change state from "pending..." to "accepted"

I have started the module but I just can't seem to find any clear documentation about making API Calls or POST requests from Magento that I'm beginning to wonder if this is actually possible?

I would be grateful if anyone knows of an extenion or documentation on how to do the above or if they know of a simpler solution...

If neccessary I can submit my module on Github as a reference if someone is able to assist me

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a custom block to the `checkout_onepage_success` layout handle via XML. This block will contain your form.
2. in the controller that processes your form, you can use [**`Zend_Http_Client`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html) to make the POST request to the third party API. Alternatively [**`Zend_Rest_Client`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.rest.client.html) or [**`Zend_Soap_Client`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.soap.client.html) or [**`Zend_XmlRpc_Client`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html) if any of these protocols are used. All of those Zend packages are readily available in Magento.
3. this is just basic loading and updating models, you should already know how to do this